# Array as property in properties window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, userform

Using Visual Studio 2012 Express.
I have a UserControl with more properties which can be set from the properties window at design-time.
The name of the UserControl is "Drum".
One property is named IsSlaveOf, and is defined as follows:

```
[Category("Custom")]
public Drum IsSlaveOf
{
    get
    {
        return _isSlaveOf;
    }
    set
    {
        _isSlaveOf = value;
    }
}
```

As you can see this property can be set to a reference of an instance of "Drum".
In my project there are several instances of the UserControl "Drum".
In the properties window at design time I can choose from a drop-down list one of the other instances that exist in my project.
So far so good.

"Drum" contains another property called IsMasterOf, and is defined as follows:

```
[Category("Custom")]
public Drum[] IsMasterOf
{
    get
    {
        return _isMasterOf;
    }
    set
    {
        _isMasterOf= value;
    }
}
```

Notice that this property is an array, than means, you should have the possibility to choose more instances in the properties window.
The problem is that in the properties window you will now see a "Drum Collection Editor", where it is not possible to choose existing instances of "Drum", it is only possible to create new instances.
If I try to enter the name of an existing instance I get a message that tells me that this component already exists.
So far I have worked it out by manually setting the property in the Designer.cs file for my main form, but this is obviously not the correct way to go.

How can you make this property so it will be possible to choose existing instances from the properties window?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Side-note: are you aware of automatically implemented properties? They could radically reduce the amount of cruft here: `public Drum IsSlaveOf { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, but if I need to control the property later on (what is entered etc.) I have to do it my way anyway, so I just do it the hard way from the beginning :) Or would it change anything in regard to my issue?

Comment: No, it wouldn't affect the issue at all - but I'd strongly encourage you to use automatically implemented properties until you need to add extra logic. If you only need to add extra logic for 10% of the properties, you're saving 10 lines of cruft for each of the other 90% of properties. The good thing is that it's entirely backwards-compatible, because it *is* a property - it's not like exposing a public field and then turning that into a property.

Comment: Properties that are arrays are already pretty ho-hum, there isn't any way to detect that the client is modifying an array element.  Also expecting them to be editable in a PropertyGrid or the Properties window doesn't make it better.  You'll need a UITypeEditor.

Comment: I'm just confused that it is possible to select an already existing instance from a dropdown list in the properties window when the property is not an array, but in case of an array I can only create new!

Comment: Hi, and sorry for the delayed answer. Hans, can you please make it as an answer, so I can accept it. UITypeEditor seems to be the way to go. I'll implement it when I get time for it.